# Upload file to GCS from Appengine (Endpoints). AttributeTypeError:

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm trying to upload a file to GCS from Appengine Endpoints. I'm using Python. When the file ends to upload, shows an error " **AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'ToMessage'** ".

So, if I go to GCS File Explorer, in the browser, I see the recently filename uploaded but its size is 0K.

This is my model:

```
class File(EndpointsModel):
    _message_fields_schema = ('blob', 'url')

    blob = ndb.BlobKeyProperty() #stored in GCS
    url = ndb.StringProperty()
    enable = ndb.BooleanProperty(default=True)

    def create_file(filename):
        file_info = blobstore.FileInfo(filename)
        filename = '/gs'+ str(file_info.filename.blob)

        gcs.open(secrets.BUCKET_NAME +'/' + filename, 'w').close()
        return blobstore.create_gs_key(filename)
```

So, what I need to do to upload correctly a file to GCS from Appengine Endpoints.

Traceback:

```
ERROR    2014-11-25 20:35:22,654 service.py:191] Encountered unexpected error from ProtoRPC method implementation: AttributeError ('str' object has no attribute 'ToMessage')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/alpocr/workspace/google_appengine/lib/protorpc-1.0/protorpc/wsgi/service.py", line 181, in protorpc_service_app
response = method(instance, request)
 File "/home/alpocr/workspace/google_appengine/lib/endpoints-1.0/endpoints/api_config.py", line 1332, in invoke_remote
return remote_method(service_instance, request)
File "/home/alpocr/workspace/google_appengine/lib/protorpc-1.0/protorpc/remote.py", line 412, in invoke_remote_method
response = method(service_instance, request)
File "/home/alpocr/workspace/mall4g-backend/libs/endpoints_proto_datastore/ndb/model.py", line 1429, in EntityToRequestMethod
response = response.ToMessage(fields=response_fields)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'ToMessage'
```

Comment: Please include the **full** traceback of the error.

Comment: I have updated the post with traceback.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have defined the return type correctly for your endpoints method, and it's expecting to turn the result into a Message object, but the endpoints method code is actually returning a string. Can you post the endpoints method that is called when this error occurs?

Either that or endpoints proto model is acting weird when you (somewhere in your code) assign a string value to one of its properties. When it tries to convert it to a Message (and thus recursively to turn its properties into Messages), it finds the String and bugs out. It's hard to tell without seeing the affected endpoint method's code.

---

UPDATE: Also, checking the source of `endpoints_proto_datastore`, [we see the following comment](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/endpoints-proto-datastore/blob/master/endpoints_proto_datastore/ndb/model.py#L1412) above the line that bugs:

```
# If developers using a custom request message class with
# response_fields to create a response message class for them, it is
# up to them to return an instance of the current EndpointsModel
# class. If not, their API users will receive a 503 from an uncaught
# exception.
```

Could this apply to you?